# Clipboard contents are changed without warning by TextMate

Tags: macos, clipboard, textmate

If I copy a section of text from Chrome (also Safari, TextEdit, etc.) and look at what is in the clipboard the types listed (this example is for Chrome) are:

```
(
    "public.utf8-plain-text",
    NSStringPboardType,
    "public.html",
    "Apple HTML pasteboard type"
)
```

But then—and this is twisted—*just bring TextMate to the front and immediately go back to your original application* — and now the types are:

```
(
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y82ppnvw1u7crqf4gnydcr7u1e3cytf2gn",
    OakTextMatePboardType,
    "public.utf8-plain-text",
    NSStringPboardType
)
```

OakTextMatePboardType is proprietary TextMate type.  The upshot of this is that the html content of the pasteboard is gone, as is any formatting that an application might derive from the html.

TextMate has something called a clipboard manager; do I need to find it and disable it?

TextMate Version 1.5.10 (1631) OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with Version 1.5.11 (1634). Do you have any non-default bundles installed?

Comment: Nope, nothing non-default that I know of.  But maybe something from older versions?  I just deleted all traces of previous installs and re-downloaded latest from website.  Problem remains!  My (PyObjC) code calls `pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard().types()`  but list of pasteboard types confirmed also via an app [Pasteboard Inspector](http://download.cnet.com/Pasteboard-Inspector/3000-2247_4-54643.html).  To repeat:  (1) copy text with formatting, (2) paste into blank TextEdit page, (3)  bring TextMate to front (4) paste into TextEdit.  Expect: same formatting from (2)  See: no formatting.